# Trouble with bandwith/memory usage in a php proxy for streaming video

Tags: php, memory, video, proxy, streaming

I am using a simple (unsafe) php script to stream video through  my server.

```
<?php
if(checkToken($_SESSION['token']) && isLoggedIn() && checkIsVideo($_GET['url'])){

    $dirFile = $_GET['url']; // http://othersite.com/video.mp4
    header("Content-Type: video/mp4");

    $fh = @fopen($dirFile, "rb") or die();
    while (!feof($fh)){
        print(fread($fh, 1048576));
        @ob_end_flush();
        @ob_flush();
        @flush();
        @ob_start();
    }
    fclose($fh);
}
exit();
?>
```

However this php link (http://mysite123.com/proxy.php?url=othersite.com/video.mp4) is been used by every single user in my website.

This means that I could have trouble with the memory limit of php, which by the way I know I can change it in "php.ini" file. However, I would like to know a better solution, to make this php proxy script a less consuming task in my server. So that I could, also, handle the bandwidth and pay less ;)

Again, I'm also thinking in building a proxy server only for this "streaming video proxy" task. And that way I can have a website server and a proxy server. Each one capable of managing its traffic.

I guess I could get a proxy server and use a link like:

http://myproxy.com/?url=othersite.com/video.mp4

I would like to hear your ideas/solutions about this issue.

Thanks :)

EDIT: these video files are usually 150 MB

Comment: All those `@` just makes my eyes shine ;)

Comment: Maybe you can setup a queue in order to limitate the simultaneously connected users ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been working with Nginx for the last 2 years, and I can say it's one of your best choices. Why?

> 1) It's free 2) Has got a good support team 3) A nice module for your
>   mp4 streaming: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_mp4_module.html
>   4) high performance, you don't need to worry about memory and cpu
>   consumption anymore

Comment: So are you suggesting getting a proxy server and install Nginx for the "proxy streaming" task ?

Comment: You don't need a proxy server. Install nginx as your main webserver and you are done!

Comment: could you guide me on this. Could you give me a link which can help me achieve this ?

Comment: but the problem of the php memory is still there

Comment: No its not there. Your php code must change to redirect the user to specific url which will be used for streaming... your php will be executed for few millisecond and will exit! This is what I am trying to tell you, let nginx handle the streaming part!